# Freewheel diode / capacitor with this board?

Tags: arduino, motor, protection

With DC motors, it is common to put a freewheel diode and/or a capacitor in order to protect the equipment as the motor can induce current into the system.

I plan to use [this board](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf2/md10crev2.0usersmanual_2015-07.pdf) to control a 24V DC motor with a Arduino-like microcontroler. In an example in their documentation, they don't put such protection, so I wanted to know if it's unsafe, or is it that the board already protects the system?

The example in question:
[image: Example]

Comment: That's a great question for [electronics.SE], but not so much for our site that's related to robotics.

Comment: I agree this is a great question for [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). But I disagree that it is off-topic here, since it seems to fall under the very first bullet-point in ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I've since also asked the question on electrical engineering @david

Comment: Where? Oh, I see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216184/freewheel-diode-capacitor-with-this-board .

Comment: I agree with @DavidCarey - If a question about motor drive circuitry doesn't belong here then I don't know what does. Granted EE can answer (and already have, which is why I'm not voting to re-open) but the same can be said of basically any question that could be asked here.